# In how many ways can four prizes be distributed to three persons if every person receives at least one prize?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been working on this combinatorics problem and found this post with a similar problem where they develop the solution: [In how many ways can $6$ prizes be distributed among $4$ persons such that each one gets at least one prize?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553023/in-how-many-ways-can-6-prizes-be-distributed-among-4-persons-such-that-each)

If the problem is simplified into 3 prizes for 2 people you get the following answer:

$$2^3 - {2\choose 1} 1^3 = 8 - 2 = 6$$

I get that the -2 are the distributions where a person receives three prizes.

And when doing the distributions for 4 prizes for 3 people you get:

$$3^4 - {3\choose 2} 2^4 + {3\choose 1} 1^4 = 81 -48 + 3=36$$
In this answer the 48 distributions subtracted are the distributions where at least one person doesn't get any prize, but which distributions are added from the +3?

Comment: You should have $3^4 - \binom{3}{2}2^4 + \binom{3}{1}1^4$.

Comment: Thanks! I copied it from the question linked.

Answer (score 1):

A possibly easier solution: Temporarily imagine a fourth person, and give everybody one prize. This can be done in $4!=24$ ways. Now disqualify the fourth person and award his prize to one of the others. This can be done in $3$ ways, as you have $3$ others to give the prize to. You now have the situation in the question, but each distribution has been counted twice, because the person with two prizes could have had either of those prizes initially and gotten the other one from the disqualified person. So we divide by $2$ to correct the overcount. We get $24\times3/2=36$.

Answer (score 0):

The term $\binom{3}{1}1^4$ comes from the number of ways to distribute the four presents if at least two persons don't get any prize. The $\binom{3}{1}$ is the number of ways to select the lucky person to get the prizes, and $1^4$ represents how many ways to distribute the four presents to the selected person.

Comment: But then these 3 ways to distribute doesn't apply because two persons don't get any prize and the restriction is that everybody gets at least one.

Comment: @inrer Are you aware of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?